# Error: unrecognized arguments in Python script

Tags: c#, python-3.x, string, shell, csv

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET Webforms. To do this, I need to use Python scripts, including one that requires arguments. One of the arguments in this script is a string designating a path to a "csv" file (`path = C:\Windows\path\to\a\file.csv`).
You will find a part of my C# script that allows me to run a Python script (pythonPath is the path to a python executable file and scriptPath is the path to my python script) :

```
public static Dictionary<String,float> EvaluationModel(string trainingPath, string pythonPath, string scriptPath, string regressionType, string testPath, string targetVariable, List<String> predVariables, string parameters, string booster)
    { 
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = pythonPath;

        // Provide script and arguments
        var script = scriptPath;

        psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{"--regressor " + regressionType}\" \"{"--path " + trainingPath}\" \"{"--test_path "+ testPath }\" \"{"--label " + targetVariable}\" \"{"--pred_vars " + string.Join(" ", predVariables.ToArray()) }\" \"{"--para " + parameters}\" \"{"--booster " + booster}\"";
```

When I try to run my script on C# I get an error message like this :"`script_training.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --regressor xgboost --path C:\Users\path\to\train.csv --test_path C:\Users\path\to\test.csv --label Label --pred_vars feature --para 1 1 100 0.1 1 1 1 --booster gbtree`"

I tried to execute the script by using Python in command-line and it got the same problem. However, I solved the problem by using double quotes in my path strings : "C:\Users\path\to\file.csv".
I tried to use double quotes in between my path strings by using `"\"" + trainingPath + "\""` but it didn't work and I got this error message : " `script_training.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --regressor xgboost --path "C:\Users\path\to\train.csv" --test_path "C:\Users\path\to\test.csv" --label Label --pred_vars feature --para 1 1 100 0.1 1 1 1 --booster gbtree` "

Can you help me to solve this problem of input arguments?

Comment: Have you tried to store the command in a string first then log it to the console to see if it is actually constructed correctly eg. `string path =  $"\"{script}\" \"{"--regressor " + regressionType}\" \"{"--path " + trainingPath}\" \"{"--test_path "+ testPath }\" \"{"--label " + targetVariable}\" \"{"--pred_vars " + string.Join(" ", predVariables.ToArray()) }\" \"{"--para " + parameters}\" \"{"--booster " + booster}\"";`

Comment: Try using @ before the string. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: How can I use @ before a string variable that is already set?

Comment: Does "--para 1 1 100 0.1 1 1 1" not need quotes round it to block together parameters? eg -para "1 1 100.0 1 1 1"

Comment: The extra quotes round things will confuse it yes

Comment: @Steve, I tried to implement your suggestion and I got this string : ```"C:\Users\path\to\script_training.py" "--regressor xgboost" "--path "C:\Users\path\to\train.csv"" "--test_path "C:\Users\path\to\test.csv"" "--label Label" "--pred_vars features" "--para 3 1 100 0.1 1 1 1" "--booster gbtree"``` EDIT : I think it's due to the quotes between each argument.

Comment: @BugFinder do you know how to make sure that the Python executable can read the string correctly ?

Comment: @BugFinder, I didn't need to use quotes for "--para 1 1 100 0.1 1 1 1" to execute the code on the shell.

Comment: How do you form it on the command line?

Comment: In command line I just type : ```py script_training.py --regressor xgboost --path "C:\Users\path\to\train.csv" --test_path "C:\Users\path\to\test.csv" --label Label --pred_vars features --para 3 1 100 0.1 1 1 1 --booster gbtree```

Comment: @BugFinder , do you think I should type : ```$"\"{script} {"--regressor " + regressionType} {"--path " + trainingPath} {"--test_path " + testPath } {"--label " + targetVariable} {"--pred_vars " + string.Join(" ", predVariables.ToArray()) } {"--para " + parameters} {"--booster " + booster}"``` instead of the other command?

Comment: No I think you should just have Arguments = @"{script} --regressor xgboost --path ""C:\Users\path\to\train.csv"" --test_path ""C:\Users\path\to\test.csv"" --label Label --pred_vars features --para 3 1 100 0.1 1 1 1 --booster gbtree"

Comment: @BugFinder I will try it but I don't know how will I put my variables with your solution.

Comment: @BugFinder I used an ```@``` at the beginning of the string and I get this error message ```C:\path\to\python.exe: can't open file '{script}': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```

EDIT : I used ```$@``` instead of ```@``` and it worked!

Comment: that @ was supposed to be a $ .. you can put your variables in or concatenate them.. choice is yours (suffering migraine atm, and trying to do dayjob)

Comment: @BugFinder, I tried to use $@ at the beginning of my formatted string and I got another error. If I remove the @, everything is okay.

Comment: As I said it was supposed to be a $ .. (seeing with a migraine is harder than it sounds)

Comment: @BugFinder Yes I know but $ didn't work (because of the string path).

Comment: Then pad the \ with \\ the problem was you werent trying to send the same string - you should have been able to play around until the string you generated was the same as what you supplied on a working commandline

Comment: Thank you very much @BugFinder it solved the problem !!!!